# Access typescript global variable outside of angular controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I've one global variable called `rowTag` as array of `Tag[]` entity in main.ts file.

I've one angular controller called `TagMeController.ts` file

Here is a constructor of `TagMeController`

```
constructor($scope, $rootScope) {
            $scope.CloseMe = this.CloseMe;
            $scope.rowTags = rowTag;//rowTag global variable
            $scope.colTags = colTag;//colTag global variable
            $scope.UpdateMe = this.UpdateMe;
        }
```

So, when I update `rowTag` object from the same controller, it update respective element on UI but when I update same object from some another `.ts(main.ts)` file things are not being reflected.

Any idea on how to make that variable observable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea on how to make that variable observable

Create an *angular service* to contain that piece of information,

```
class Tags {
    rowTags = [] 
    colTags = []
}
```

and then use that service :

```
constructor($scope, $rootScope, tags: Tags) {
    $scope.CloseMe = this.CloseMe;
    $scope.tags = tags; // Tags service containing `rowTag` and `colTag`
    $scope.UpdateMe = this.UpdateMe;
}
```

Here is a video on creating an angular service using TypeScript : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM

Comment: Could you please add more details on this ?